# Generating Thumbnails for PDF

Tags: pdf, imageresizer

i have to generate preview thumbnails for a bunch of user generated pdfs.
Therefor i have a asp.net mvc5 application with imageresizing.net.

Now i have the problem, that the PdfRenderer crashes due a multithreading problem in Ghostscript.

As a next step i have written a custom Handler for *.pdf, which does the scaling and caching manually.

And now the question: how can i disable the mapping for .pdf to the imageresizing.net engine, as i want to handle the scaling and caching by myself?

Answer (score 0):

If you uninstall the PdfRenderer plugin, it will stop catching those file extensions.

You might also consider trying PdfiumRenderer; PDFium is better the Ghostscript for most tasks, and is not GPL-licensed.

Comment: Hi, but how can i use the PDFRenderer/PDFium from managed code if the plugin is not installed? do you have a sample for this?

Comment: You can have multiple Config instances. Install it on a `new Config()` instead of via Config.Current